# The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable

Tags: python, pandas, xml, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am a complete noob and im trying to run a Google Cloud Function that would create a view in BigQuery based on a Pandas dataframe. The dataframe would be created appending 3 XML files with exchangerates, and the code works perfectly on VSCode. I want the function to be a 2nd generation function and be triggered via HTTPS without authentication.

I tried to base the Google Cloud Function on the article published in https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-upload-data-to-google-bigquery-using-python-in-3-steps-7138ae625fe3, but few seconds later launches the error:

"Could not create or update Cloud Run service function-1, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'function-1-00001-jib' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable."

The code I came up for the function is the following:

`

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from pandas.io import gbq
import pandas_gbq
import gcsfc
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def validate_http(request):
  request.json = request.get_json()
  
  if request.args:
    get_api_data()
    return f'Data pull complete'
  
  elif request_json:
    get_api_data()
    return f'Data pull complete'
  
  else:
    get_api_data()
    return f'Data pull complete'

  
def get_api_data():
  
    url_19 = "https://www.bnr.ro/files/xml/years/nbrfxrates2019.xml"
    url_20 = "https://www.bnr.ro/files/xml/years/nbrfxrates2020.xml"
    url_21 = "https://www.bnr.ro/files/xml/years/nbrfxrates2021.xml"

    url_list = [url_19,url_20, url_21]

    date_list = []
    eur_list = []
    usd_list = []

    def filler (url):
        response = requests.get(url).content    

        tree = ET.fromstring(response)

        for child in tree:
            for subchild in child:
                for subsubchild in subchild:
                    if subsubchild.attrib['currency'] == "EUR":
                        date_list.append(subchild.attrib['date'])
                        eur_list.append(subsubchild.text)
                    if subsubchild.attrib['currency'] == "USD":
                        usd_list.append(subsubchild.text)

    for url_address in url_list:
        filler(url_address)

    data_tuples = list(zip(date_list, eur_list, usd_list))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_tuples, columns=['Date', 'EUR', "USD"])  
    
    bq_load('exchange_rate', df)
 
  
def bq_load(key, value):
  
  project_name = 'fabled-badge-351251'
  dataset_name = 'liquor_sales'
  table_name = key
  
  value.to_gbq(destination_table='liquor_sales.exchange_rate'.format(dataset_name, table_name), project_id=project_name, if_exists='replace')
```

`
The requirements.txt:

functions-framework==3.*

pandas==1.2.2

pandas_gbq

pandas.io

requests==2.21.0

gcsfs

Does anyone have an idea of what i am doing wrong?

Comment: The URL `https://www.originaldata.xml` doesn't not exist. So you can't process the data

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i am sorry, was a mistake copying from another example. I inserted the correct URLs now in the edited question